# Giving the option of saving the same data over again,

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management

I have an app that gets the user's current location (using core location, etc.) and the user can save that location. How would I prevent the user from saving the same locations over and over again? Or if they do want to save the same location but replace the old information, how would I do that? How would I be able to tackle this problem?

import Foundation
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

extension Location {

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Location> {

    return NSFetchRequest<Location>(entityName: "Location")
}

@NSManaged public var latitude: Double
@NSManaged public var longitude: Double
@NSManaged public var date: Date
@NSManaged public var locationDescription: String
@NSManaged public var category: String
@NSManaged public var placemark: CLPlacemark?
```

}

Comment: Hey... You need to provide more details, context and code snippets for the community to help you out.

Comment: Couldn't you check if the location is the same (with needed accuracy) before you save it?

Comment: Thanks for giving your feedback. But Dasdom how would be able to do that.